# What are some quality small business management programs?

Tags: software-recommendation

I manage a small lawn business, I currently use about 12 tabs in Excel and keep track of customers, expenses, income, payroll, etc. I now have an iMac and am wondering what quality small business management programs are available.

Comment: Is there software on other platforms you have used in the past that has features you would hope to replicate? If not, what features are you looking for or what do you want the software to do that your current setup in Excel doesn't do for you?

Comment: I'm open to new ways of storing and entering data. i like the way excel calculates its formulas. Is there something that is compatible with my iPhone to where i can update data on the job site as well as behind the desk?

Comment: @Cte Numbers for iPhone can probably accomplish that. However, it's much easier to use on an iPad (larger screen.)

Comment: okay awesome ill definitely check it out. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

There's always [Office for Mac](http://www.microsoftstore.ca/shop/en-CA/Microsoft/Office/Office-for-Mac-2011?WT.term=%2Boffice+%2Bmac+download&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_Microsoft+CA_google_Office+for+Mac+2011&WT.medium=cpc&WT.campaign=Office+for+Mac+2011&WT.srch=1&WT.content=nGvFN4uz&WT.source=google&cshift_ck=e0bbf2f2-c69c-4d3c-a49f-2b72c43c3026csnGvFN4uz) if you like Excel, [Numbers](http://www.apple.com/iwork/numbers/), and a host of other business apps. Check out the Mac App Store's "Business" section for more. Do realize, however, that Office for Mac isn't exactly the same as it is on Windows, and may *not necessarily* be worth the hefty price tag.

Comment: okay thank you for your help! I'm gonna check out numbers

Comment: No problem. It's reasonably priced, compared to some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Books by Geode Software provides complete accounting, invoicing, and time-tracking functions on your Mac – which looks like it's a good fit for your lawn business.